# To find the overlapping of two date ranges and merge it into one date range in JAVA

Tags: java, date

We have blocks with specific no. of date ranges, and require to merge the date ranges of every block which are overlapping and add their overall quantity.

Consider the below given input and desired output:

### Input:

```
Block 1 -

14/11/2016 - 17/11/2016     ===>  100

18/11/2016 - 20/11/2016     ===>  200

Block 2 -

15/11/2016 - 16/11/2016     ===>  50

17/11/2016 - 20/11/2016     ===>  300

Block 3 -

15/11/2016 - 18/11/2016     ===>  100

19/11/2016 - 20/11/2016     ===>  400
```

### Desired Output:

```
14/11/2016                  ===> 100

15/11/2016 - 16/11/2016     ===> 250

17/11/2016                  ===> 500

18/11/2016                  ===> 600

19/11/2016 - 20/11/2016     ===> 900
```

Please could you advise if any java utility to handle this complexity.

Comment: What have you tried? We are here to help you with your problems, not do it for you. Try adding your attempt or tell us what you have tried to do to solve the problem.

Comment: I would merge them using 1+2 and then +3, adding together overlapping regions. You need the ranges to be sorted, and then do a type of merge sort. You could have a `SortedMap<Interval, Integer>` where `Interval` is a pair of `LocalDate`s.

Comment: Please search Stack Overflow before posting. This has been covered already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utility unknown, but you could compute your answers with an array of integers where the data representation of the index of the array is the offset of each day from a start point, and then you iterate over every range and increment the value of the range into the corresponding indices of the array, then when you're done, each index represents the offset date of a start date and the value is the accumulated value from the ranges in the blocks. Then if you want to have the output represented by ranges again, you can step through the content and declare start and end points of ranges based on consecutive matching values.

`set start date = day of first entry of first block
for each block
    for each range
        for each day of range
            offset = day-of-range - start-date
            array[offset] += rangeValue`

Picture it like stacking timelines together, then letting them all project down into a common discrete set of holders which aggregate the value landing in each holder.

`new range(start date, start date)
range-value = array[0]
for each index in array
    if array[index] == array[index-1]
        range-end = startdate+index
    else
        new range(startdate+index, startdate+index)
        range-value = array[index]`

Not accounting for index bounds at the start or error traps. It may not be the most elegant solution, but it should solve your problem.